# Do I need to put the list back into treemap after adding to it

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

Imagine I have a TreeMap<Integer, List> and then I call get(x) out of the TreeMap to get an existing list in the treemap and then with that list I then .add a new item into the list do I then need to put that list back into the treemap or is it automatically now in there so when I call 'get' on the treemap next that new item will also be in that list already without having called put to put it back in?

Hopefully that makes sense lol, any confirmation is appreciated!

Comment: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: So yes I need to be putting this values back in?

Comment: No, the list is already in the Map, so just add to it and no need to put it back.